# ActionScript Mouse_Move Only While Mouse_Down?

Tags: actionscript-3, mouseevent

i'm attempting to implement a mouse event where Mouse_Move can only occur if Mouse_Down.  i could introduce a boolean that would toggle during Mouse_Down and Mouse_Up that could work, but is there a better way, perhaps a more official way, of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply add the the MOUSE_MOVE event listener on MOUSE_DOWN, and then remove it on MOUSE_UP.

Hope that helps.